# I want to use IF and multiple ORs with ANDs together in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am having an issue on excel 2010: I want to say

> IF (G3="a" AND G2>0) OR if (G3="b" AND G2>1) OR if (G3="c" AND G2>2) OR if (G3="d" AND G2>3) THEN "YES"

I have tried many attempts to code this. Any help?
Here is the code I am trying to fix:

```
=IF(OR(AND(G3="a",F3>=1)),(AND(G3="b",F3>1)),(AND(G3="c",F3>2)),"Yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got some mismatching parentheses. Try this instead of what you had.

```
=IF(OR(AND(G3="a",F3>=1),AND(G3="b",F3>1),AND(G3="c",F3>2)),"Yes")
```

This version matches your quote.

```
=IF(OR(AND(G3="a",G2>0),AND(G3="b",G2>1),AND(G3="c",G2>2),AND(G3="d",G2>3)),"Yes")
```

Comment: most likely yours is the correct one, as I believe the OP simplified the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the formula to:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(FIND(G3,"abcd")),F3>CODE(G3)-97),"Yes","No")
```

Assuming that your data provided is a simplification, here is another formula that uses INDEX,MATCH instead of AND/OR:

```
=IF(F3>IFERROR(INDEX({0,1,2,3},MATCH(G3,{"a","b","c","d"},0)),1E+99),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: This is very clever but the `CODE` part doesn't generalize easily.

Comment: @AlexisOlson as I said in your comments, this works for the data provided, my guess is yours will be the one that the OP goes with as I believe the data is generalized and not this exact pattern, which would invalidate this answer.  But, it answers what is asked.

Comment: It does indeed. My comment was more directed more at OP or other readers who may stumble upon this. I know you understand.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Ok, made it more robust.